# Back End Of Azure Data Factory?

Tags: azure-data-factory

A lot of information is saved internally when we create pipelines and publish in Azure Data Factory. When we create pipelines and Trigger them, the history is saved somewhere. Where exactly and how can we access it. I am not referring to the Monitor page but where that page gets the data ?
May be I missed it in the documentation and am unable to get hold of it.

Thanks
- Akshay

Comment: I think you are looking for this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/monitor-programmatically

Comment: The link shows a way to access it for 45 days which is the MAX (Default). However I am searching for where these Information is stored. JSON, XML, SQL ?

Comment: Which data you want to find out in pipeline running history?

Comment: Where it is stored. What format ?  Azure data monitor would also either save data in itself somewhere or fetch it from somewhere. I am looking for that specific information.

Answer (score 1):

The Azure Data Factory pipeline run metadata is stored at Azure Data Factory web server database, which is accessible via Azure SDKs. For example, if you can use Python, you can create a data factory Python client and extract pipeline runs/activity runs metadata. You can then parse the response metedata into a pandas dataframe and write to a database table.

The below function can be used to do so.

```
def adf_logging():
    # Azure subscription ID
    subscription_id = ''
    # Azure resource group
    rg_name = ''
    # The data factory name. It must be globally unique.
    df_name = ''
    credentials = ServicePrincipalCredentials(
                                client_id='',
                                secret='',
                                tenant='')
    # Create a data factory client.
    adf_client = DataFactoryManagementClient(credentials, subscription_id)
    filter_parameters = {"lastUpdatedAfter": "2019-08-06T00:36:44.3345758Z",
                         "lastUpdatedBefore": "2019-08-07T00:49:48.3686473Z"}
    # Extract last 24 hours pipeline run metadata.
    pipeline_runs = adf_client.pipeline_runs.query_by_factory(rg_name, df_name, filter_parameters)
    # Iterate and parse metadata, get log stats.
    cols = ['Pipeline_Name', 'Pipeline_Run_Id', 'Pipeline_Run_Status', 
            'Activity_Name', 'Activity_Start_Time', 'Activity_End_Time', 
            'Activity_Run_Status', 'Data_Read',
            'Data_Written', 'Rows_Read', 'Rows_Written', 'Copy_Duration', 
             'Error_Message']
    df_stats = pd.DataFrame(columns=cols)
    for i in pipeline_runs.as_dict()['value']:
        pipeline_name = i['pipeline_name']
        run_id = i['run_id']
        pipeline_run_status = i['status']
        activity_runs = list(adf_client.activity_runs.list_by_pipeline_run(
                                              rg_name, 
                                              df_name, run_id,                                                                 
                                              datetime.now() - timedelta(1),
                                              datetime.now() + timedelta(1)))
        # Parse activity run metadata.
        for activity_run in activity_runs:
            if re.match(r"Lookup_[A-Z]", activity_run.activity_name):
                pass
            elif re.match(r"If_[A-Z]", activity_run.activity_name):
                pass
            elif re.match(r"ForEach_[A-Z]", activity_run.activity_name):
                pass
            elif re.match(r"Success [A-Z]", activity_run.activity_name):
                pass
            else:
                activity_name = activity_run.activity_name
                start_time = activity_run.activity_run_start
                start_time = start_time.replace(tzinfo=None)
                end_time = activity_run.activity_run_end
                end_time = end_time.replace(tzinfo=None)
                activity_run_status = activity_run.status
                data_read = activity_run.output['dataRead'] / (1000*1000)
                data_write = activity_run.output['dataWritten'] / (1000*1000)
                rows_read = activity_run.output['rowsRead']
                rows_write = activity_run.output['rowsCopied']
                copy_duration = activity_run.output['copyDuration']
                error_message = activity_run.output['errors']

                data = {'Pipeline_Name': pipeline_name, 'Pipeline_Run_Id':run_id,
                        'Pipeline_Run_Status': pipeline_run_status,
                        'Activity_Name': activity_name, 
                        'Activity_Start_Time': start_time,
                        'Activity_End_Time': end_time, 
                        'Activity_Run_Status': activity_run_status,
                        'Data_Read': data_read, 'Data_Written': data_write,
                        'Rows_Read': rows_read, 'Rows_Written': rows_write,
                        'Copy_Duration': copy_duration, 
                        'Error_Message': error_message}

                df = pd.DataFrame([data])
                df_stats = df_stats.append(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

All the information you could get is what [monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/monitor-visually) feature shows for you in ADF. That's the built-in feature.

[image]

If you do want to know what place these data reside exactly,you need to persist them. Please refer to this [statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/monitor-using-azure-monitor#persist-data-factory-data) in this document:

> Data Factory only stores pipeline run data for 45 days. If you want to
>   persist pipeline run data for more than 45 days, using Azure Monitor,
>   you cannot only route diagnostic logs for analysis, you can persist
>   them into a storage account so you have factory information for the
>   duration of your choosing.

You could store the log information with Diagnostic Log.Please see this [link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/adf-logs-in-dedicated-tables/) or this third-party [management tool](https://www.datadoghq.com/dg/logs/azure-data-factory-logs/?utm_source=Advertisement&utm_medium=GoogleAdsNon1stTierLogs&utm_campaign=GoogleAdsNon1stTierLogs-AzureData&utm_content=Logs&utm_keyword=%2Bdata%20%2Bfactory%20%2Blog&utm_matchtype=b&gclid=Cj0KCQjwyerpBRD9ARIsAH-ITn_Hd4x1CCZyH8-6bfl9N6eCRGAmu-zjKurvtC_OtH9uzlpp_NldIbIaAvs9EALw_wcB).

Comment: Thanks Jay for giving some information about the Metrics, but where exactly are the metrics stored for ADF Executions natively (before enabling diagnostics) and in what Format ? JSON ?

Answer (score 0):

We can see the all the operations log from the Azure Data Factory Active log:
[image]

I'm not sure where the log stored, but you can download ADF logs with PowerShell.

You can run [`Save-AzureRmDataFactoryLog`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.datafactories/save-azurermdatafactorylog?view=azurermps-6.13.0) cmdlet with Id value you see from the output and download the log files using the -DownloadLogsoption for the cmdlet.

For example:

```
 Save-AzureRmDataFactoryLog -ResourceGroupName "ADF" -DataFactoryName "LogProcessingFactory" -Id "841b77c9-d56c-48d1-99a3-8c16c3e77d39" -DownloadLogs -Output "C:\Test"
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. It does answer "How can we access" using the UI. "Where it is stored" is still in question.

Comment: @Akshay I'm not sure where it store, but we can get pipeline history or log with powershell. If my answer is helpful for you, can you think about accept it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Comment: I would like to keep the question open till someone finds an answer :) .  I have posted this on MSDN as well for information. Refer [Link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/monitor-azure-data-factory-pipelines-using-operations-management-suite/) .